# Rails 3 getting wrong count in query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get the number of messages that haven't been read.

The Message model has a column called read_at. If the message has been read there is a value in read_at, if it's unread then that value is nil.

I have one read message and one unread message. I get 0 unread messages (I should be getting 1). This is the code:

```
Message.all(:conditions => 
  ['website_id = ? AND read_at = ?', current_website.id, nil]).count
```

It seems that the query is right, since the development log is showing me

```
Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" 
                        WHERE (website_id = 2 AND read_at = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the problem is the one pointed by @pdjota, you should use Rails 3 notation, here is how I would write it:

```
Message.where('website_id = ? AND read_at IS NULL', current_website.id).count
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of  `read_at = NULL`
try `read_at is null`, it is a SQL thing.

```
:conditions => ['website_id = ? AND read_at is ?', current_website.id, nil]
```

Here is a short article on SQL nulls, and how to use them:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Hope it helps

---

Comment: Correct. The Rails *conditions* or *where* clause is one of the few places where you need to dive into the SQL itself. And SQL treats nulls in special ways in expressions.